# Objective c and struct

Tags: objective-c, struct

I have this problem. This the external library that i must use in .h file:

```
typedef struct _IPCSSContext IPCSSContext;
IPCSSContext * ipcssnew(const IPCSSCfg *_config, const IPCSSCallbacks *_callbacks, void *_user);
```

How can I use? Thanx

Comment: RTFM ? Just saying...
Seriously, this is like saying "I have a question, guess it then answer it". Can you give more info like where you got the library ? How do you want to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

First you define a variable of type `IPCSSCallbacks` whatever that might be, but it's probably a `struct` of function pointers.

Then you fill in the fields of the variable with pointers to your callback functions.

Then you call `icssnew()` passing the `IPCSSCallbacks`, the config and a pointer to *anything you like*.  This pointer will be passed untouched to your callback functions when they are called and you can do what you like with it in the callbacks (including nothing).

This is a pretty standard pattern in C for performing callbacks.